# Git editor error

Tags: git, editor, git-config

I get following error message, when I try to run `git rebase -i` for squashing my commit:

```
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 112: mate: command not found
```

How does git look for the editor?
From the `git-sh-setup` file, I can only see this method:

```
git_editor() {                                                                       
    if test -z "${GIT_EDITOR:+set}" 
    then                                                                             
        GIT_EDITOR="$(git var GIT_EDITOR)" || return $?                              
    fi                                                                               
    eval "$GIT_EDITOR" '"$@"'                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a setting in *`~/.gitconfig`* like this:

```
[core]
    editor = mate
```

If you have `textmate` added to you `PATH` then you can just changed it to: `editor = mate`.
Just make sure that it is added there.

`echo $PATH` to check if textmate is there.

---

You can also change the configuration option through `git config`. The option to chage is `core.editor`. For example:

```
$ git config core.editor        # the current set editor
mate
$ git config core.editor vim    # change editor to vim
$ git config core.editor
vim
```

to make the setting available in all your repositories add `--global` flag to `git config`

```
$ git config --global core.editor <editor-of-choice>
```

From `git help config` manpage:

> **core.editor**
>     Commands such as commit and tag that lets you edit messages by launching an editor uses the value of this variable when it is set, and
>     the environment variable GIT_EDITOR is not set. See git-var(1).

Comment: I added a couple of things, if that's ok with you.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in that script, it uses `git var`, which according to `git help var` does:

> `GIT_EDITOR`
>
> Text editor for use by `git` commands. The value is meant to be interpreted by the shell when it is used. Examples: `~/bin/vi`, `$SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE`,
>   `"C:\Program Files\Vim\gvim.exe" --nofork`.
>
> The order of preference is the `$GIT_EDITOR` environment variable, then `core.editor` configuration, then `$VISUAL`, then `$EDITOR`, and then finally `vi`.